# How to fix "long" page break?

Tags: ms-word

So, often an ordinary, normal page break looks like this: 
[image]
It's OK, has a line break, any unnecessary line breaks on the next page could be deleted.

But I have this in one of my docs: [image]
And this is bad, it's page-wide and has no line breaks after it on the same page, only on the next. and every single one of them in this doc is like that!

What causes this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you haven't specified which version of word you're using, or the context of your page breaks. Can you give some more details?

Comment: I have Word 2016, but the document, that has this bug, was made in 2003. I've saved it as copy in more up-to-date `.docx` format, but it did nothing.

Comment: OK, well off the top of my head it could be:
1) a paragraph break that has somehow got itself caught in a cross reference
or 2) a paragraph break that is formatted in a different style to the normal font/style. If it's this, you should be able to select the text on either side, and just reformat.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? My first choice would be to cut it and the paragraphs on either side, and then paste the same material back again as plain text. That should get rid of any weird formatting, and then you can re-add the page break if you want to